# Change "Existing Web Site" project type to MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, project-types

I would like to change a loaded Existing Web Site in visual studio (2012) in my solution to a MVC4 project web application ! Actually, the loaded web site (from  local IIS) is a real MVC application (so I'm not asking about some conversion ) , but visual studio is not recognize it like this !
With the existing solution, visual studio menus act like I have a webform application :
I can't add Controller neither Views or other MVC specific items !

So how can I change the project to MVC ?

Thank you !

Comment: Create a new Mvc project, open the project XML and find the project type element, close your other project edit the type in that project XML, now reopen it, delete the project you created.

Comment: I have just a .sln file ! And the structure is different from the project file !

Comment: Well there's your problem. You need a project with Mvc type. You won't be able to convert. Create the Mvc project in the solution and move your code into it.

Comment: Thank you Chris ! this is what I did !

Comment: link to list of guids: https://www.codeproject.com/reference/720512/list-of-visual-studio-project-type-guids

Answer (score 2):

I added this to my .csproj and now I have the 'Add->View' in my context when right-clicking my 'Views' folder.  Hope this helps.

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Comment: It can indeed provide 'Add->View' option in context but intellisense color-coding support would still be missing